# Some programs run on startup

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, startup

Every time I boot my laptop, two terminal window, a document viewer and a folder starts up.  Here is screenshot.
[image]

I deleted the folder so it doesn't start up. How do I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible reasons why the application is started:

1. It is saved in the last session
2. it is listed in the auto started applications.

To solve it:

1. Start the `xfce4-autostart-editor` and remove the application(s). You
   can also manually delete those files in `~/Desktop/Autostart` and
   `~/.config/autostart`.
2. Most of the time closing all the applications and save your session when you logout is sufficient. If this doesn't work, remove the content of the `~/.cache/sessions/` directory when you're not logged
   in. And if you don't want xfce remember every session you should
   turn off (uncheck) “Automatically save session on logout” in `Settings Manager → Sessions and Startup (tab General)`

Reference: [XFCE WIKI FAQ](http://wiki.xfce.org/faq).

Comment: the second one solved!! thank you all for prompt response.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha You are welcome my friend Glad to be able to help

Answer (score 2):

check your   **/etc/rc.local** file.This is file which is default startup file for ubuntu.
Whenever system reboots, it will run this file.check if this file is having any script or any command regarding those terminal window and document viewer.

Answer (score 2):

That's really crazy stuff. 
You can try to disable it from the **startup applications** tool. Search for startup applications on the menu and when the window open, you will see all the softwares that initialize with your system. 
There, you will probably see the three commands that open the two terminals and the document viewer, just disable them by clicking in remove.


Hopefully, it will stop your problem.


[image: Demonstration of the window]